# Square root of these $2\times2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am to find the matrix square root of $A$ from the following formula: $R=S^{-1}\sqrt{\Lambda S}$ and explain why there is no real matrix square root of $B$. I am stuck on A as the following calculation shows.

- Could someone nudge me slightly further in the calculation
- My book is useless at explaining everything, how does one actually get the square root of a matrix in the following formula: $R=S^{-1}\sqrt{\Lambda S}$. I understand that you must multiply the inverse matrix $S$ with $\Lambda$ but then what?

I have the eigenvalues and matrix:

$\lambda_{1} = 1,\ \lambda_{2} = 9$

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 4\\ 
4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$

And the following eigenvalues and matrix:

$\lambda_{1} = -1,\ \lambda_{2} = 9$

$B=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 5\\ 
5 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$

The first eigenvector:

$\begin{bmatrix}
5-\lambda_{1} & 4\\ 
4 & 5-\lambda_{1}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 4\\ 
4 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$

After some row elimination:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

$x_{1}=1$
$x_{2}=-1$

first eigenvector $(1,-1)$

Time to get the second eigenvector:

$\begin{bmatrix}
5-\lambda_{2} & 4\\ 
4 & 5-\lambda_{2}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & 4\\ 
4 & -4
\end{bmatrix}$

I am stuck at this point.
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Are you sure it is not just $R = S\sqrt{\Lambda}S^{-1}$ (where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix).

Comment: I'm with @flawr - you need first to write $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$, which tells you what $\Lambda$ is. Because it is a diagonal matrix it has some obvious square roots - the question would be better if asked to find a square root rather than the square root.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix

Comment: @MarkBennet Indeed! I am however stuck at trying to find $S$ :/, I get a zero matrix from the second eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your formula is slight wrong, or mistyped. It should be $S \sqrt{\Lambda}S^{-1}$.

Thus, you only have to calculate the square-root of a diagonal matrix, and this is simply done via taking the square-root of each entry.

Finally, and this might be your main problem at the moment, your last matrix is wrong, the first line should be $(-1,1)$ or something equivalent, yielding an eigenvector of the form $(1,1)$.

Then just put these two eigenvectors $(1,-1)$ that you found already, and this other $(1,1)$ as the *columns* of a matrix, this is your $S$.

Comment: Derp! Thanks pal, I wrote down the formula incorrect and did  incorrect gauss-jordan calculations. I'm back on track!

Comment: You are welcome. Please note however that I made an edit as I had a typo for the inverses. The formula is now closer, though not the same, as the one in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

To find the eigenvectors you should solve this matrix equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & 4\\ 
4 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
b
\end{bmatrix}=0$$

So we have $a-b=0$, or the second eigenvector will be

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$$